# dropdown inside the repeater in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to add `DropdownList` in repeater but what I replace instead of `grdfilapprove` in this

code

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in **GrdFileApprove**.Rows)
        {

            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DropDownList DropDownListcontrol =
               row.FindControl("DropDownList4")       as  
             DropDownList;  

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("approveddd", mySQLconnection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

I update my question 
this is button code

```
foreach (RepeaterItem row in Repeater2.Items)
        //foreach (GridViewRow row in GrdFileApprove.Rows)
        {

           if (row.**RowType** == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DropDownList DropDownListcontrol =
             ((DropDownList)**dataItem.**FindControl("DropDownList4"));
                //DropDownList DropDownListcontrol = row.FindControl("DropDownList4") 
               as DropDownList;

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("approveddd", mySQLconnection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DocID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
            Convert.ToInt32((row.Cells[1].Text));

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApproveID", SqlDbType.Int).Value =
              Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListcontrol.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApproveBy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = 
           (Session["Login2"]);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                DMSLIB.Doc myDoc = new DMSLIB.Doc();
                myDoc.MarkDocAs(Convert.ToInt16(row.**Cells**[1].Text),  
             Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListcontrol.SelectedValue));

            }
            else
            {
                apfi.Text = "Error";
            }
        }
```

now when i use this this show me error in this

1.`RowType
error   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem' does not contain a definition for 'RowType' and no extension method 'RowType' accepting a first argument of type` `'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

2.`dataItem error the name 'dataItem' does not exist in the current context`

3.Cells `System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem does not contain a definition for 'Cells' and no extension method 'Cells' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

4.Cells
    `'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem' does not contain a definition for 'Cells' and no extension method 'Cells' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

thankx

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. I guess this should be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/q/1432790/1236044

Comment: previously i use gridview but now i use repeater so when i implement repeater then what i replace this grdfileapprove..

Comment: Sorry but even though there are numerous similarities, moving from GridView to Repeater is not search and replace. You have to understand how repeater works and make some porting (which should lead you to a result similar as the one linked above)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to understand what you are looking for and I think you need this to loop in the correct item for the new repeater:

```
foreach(RepeaterItem dataItem in YourRepeater.Items)        
{ 
    DropDownList DropDownListcontrol= ((DropDownList)dataItem.FindControl("DropDownList4"));

    // Your code
}
```

Comment: plz see my update question when i implement ur code it shows me some errors

Comment: no, I have replied as soon as you ask in the forum. Forget my comment if it is a different idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Repeater's ItemDataBound. Also need to check the ItemType, like below:

```
void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
    {
        DropDownList DropDownListcontrol = e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList4") as DropDownList;
        //Do other tasks
    }
}
```