# Populating a Dropdown list, uniquely, within a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm building a catalog page for a shopping cart setup, and on that page I'm using a repeater to display each product and its data. I'd like to use a Dropdown to display from 0, up to the Product's Quantity on hand, which would make each DDL unique to the product it is associated with on the page.

I cannot seem to figure out a way to Bind the DDL in a way to do this, only have seen how to bind all of them within the repeater's ItemDataBound method.

Edit:

My Web Form

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptProducts" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptProducts_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 product">
            <img src="<%# Eval("ImageFile") %>" class="col-xs-12" alt="<%# Eval("Name") %> Product Image" />
            <h3><%# Eval("Name") %></h3>
            <p><%# Eval("ShortDescription") %></p>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

My ItemDataBound (found from another thread, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432790/populating-dropdownlist-inside-repeater-not-working))

```
protected void rptProducts_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList1");

    foreach(var prod in ProductsList)
    {
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(prod.QuantOnHand.ToString(), prod.QuantOnHand.ToString()));
    }
}
```

I'm obviously not using the ItemDataBound correctly (haven't ever used it, actually), because this binding is just adding every quantity to every dropdown list.

Comment: Can you show what you are doing inside the ItemDataBound method? There you are binding the DDL, but each can have a unique source there.

Comment: Added an edit — thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easiest way to fill a DropDownList in the ItemDataBound method. In this snippet `productQuantity` comes from the Repeater source data. But you can execute a database call to get the correct quantity also. Then you need an ID which you can get like this: `productQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(item["ID"]);`

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList1");

    //the product quantity variable
    int productQuantity = 0;

    //cast the repeater item back to a datarowview
    DataRowView item = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;

    //or if a List<objects> is bound, cast it back to it's class
    //MyClass item = e.Item.DataItem as MyClass

    //get the quantity from the repeater source item to fill the ddl
    productQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(item["quantity"]);

    //add the items to the ddl
    for (int i = 0; i < productQuantity; i++)
    {
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString() });
    }

    //add a listitem to the ddl at position 0
    ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem() { Text = "Select Quantity", Value = "" });
}
```

Comment: Yes! Quick fix, item["quantity"] here would need to be item.quantity. But thank you so much — this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for a Custom Control to me, where you have an `int` property named `Quantity`, and use that in the the `Render()` method to write out the html option elements.

Here is a simplified version. Your final code will want to handle (at least) `name` and `ID` values:

```c#
[ToolboxData("<{0}:QuantityDropDown runat=\"server\"></{0}:QuantityDropDown >")]
public class QuantityDropDown : Control
{
   public int Quantity {
       get { return (int)(ViewState["Quantity"] ?? default(int)); }
       set {ViewState["Quantity"] = value;}
   }

   protected override void Render (HtmlTextWriter writer)
   {
       writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Select);
       for (int i=0; i < Quantity; i++)
       { 
           writer.AddAttribute("value", i);
           writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Option);
           writer.Write(i.ToString());
           writer.RenderEndTag();
       } 
       writer.RenderEndTag();
       writer.WriteLine();
   }
}
```

Then you can include an instance of this control as part of your Repeater markup.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" ... >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 product">
            <img src="<%# Eval("ImageFile") %>" class="col-xs-12" alt="<%# Eval("Name") %> Product Image"/>
            <h3><%# Eval("Name") %></h3>
            <p><%# Eval("ShortDescription") %></p>
            <cc:QuantityDropDown ID="ItemQuantity" runat="server" Quantity='<%# Eval("Quantity")' />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Much appreciated! The above answer seemed to work, but I appreciate you doing this. Writing a custom control would have saved me a few hours of headache. Cheers!